# safely transfer a credit card number to paypal

Tags: c#, rest, paypal, credit-card

There is a way to store and use a customer credit card with paypal. The explanation about how to do this [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/store-a-credit-card/).
I want to use /vault/credit-card, to do this paypal asks me to include the credit card details. 
What is the safest way to do this? I'm using c# and .net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if you want to deal with credit card numbers and other details you **must** be [PCI compliant](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/). It's a long, difficult and costly process subject to frequent and tough audits.

Alternatively, you don't handle sensitive data at all, but use some cryptographic identifiers, which tell you that Bob paid for product A without disclosing any sensitive data to you.

This is what [PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/) says

> If you use the PayPal REST APIs for accepting credit card payments,
>   you handle card data directly and will need to ensure you are PCI
>   compliant.
>
> Note: Don’t want to store credit cards on your servers? You can store
>   credit card details with PayPal using the [vault](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#vault) call.

Comment: Is it safe to include  "type":"visa",
 "number":"4417119669820331",
 "expire_month":"11",
 "expire_year":"2018",
 "first_name":"Joe",
 "last_name":"Shopper" in the body? Isn't there supposed to be some kind of encryption?

Comment: If you do that, you must be PCI compliant, because it is sensitive data. You have to use encryption and have many other security measures implemented. If you use [PayPal javascript buttons](http://paypal.github.io/JavaScriptButtons/) you don't need to deal with card details - you don't ever see them.